Domain-Driven Design - DTOs: What is the correct way to apply them?
I am modeling an application following the principles of Domain-Driven Design. In one of the bounded contexts of my application, I decided to use a hexagonal architecture. I would like to know if it is correct to have a DTO in my domain layer's Repository interface to represent a filter for a complex query or if I should just use the parameters in a segregated manner. For example:
public interface ISampleRepository
{
      Task<IEnumerable<Sample>> FindByFiltersAsync(int param1, int param2, string param3, DateTime param4, int param5, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

Is it correct to use an approach where my domain layer contains an object that represents this filter? I am not sure if this violates the principles of a pure domain, as maintaining the method signature in this manner makes it very verbose. What would be the best alternative according to the guidelines defined by Eric Evans in this case?

Have you eventually considered the Specification pattern ? It is often used in DDD to implement such constraints.

I think this is just a code design issue. I don't think it's really related to DDD, DTOs or hexagonal architecture. You have a method signature that's getting noisy and has the potential to get worse.
I think you're correct to consider modelling those parameters as a type that represents the concept of a filter. This will keep the method signature neat and tidy. It will also give you room to change the filter type in the future without adding further clutter to the method signature.
